# How to preserve current session after opening app from background

Tags: android, flutter, audio-player

I installed my music app into my phone using `flutter run` and now I'm testing it. What I don't like is when I press back button on my phone, the app goes to background (but continues plaing music). But when I reopen it from background, the whole app restarts itself and the player and every change in the app is restored to the original state (playback stops). Is there a way to just continue with the current session and not restart session when switching the app from background?

The second question might be answered somewhere, I just wonder if there is similarly a way to save the state and restore it even if the app is completely closed and then freshly started?

Comment: There are couple of options for this. You can use onSavedStateInstance method or SQLLite to save the current state of the activity, The progress and timer are mostly running in your service so you should be able to grab that info from there. and basic stuff like song name, album art can go int SQLLite db. 
For short term restoration use onSavedStateInstance. For long term restoration use SQLite

Comment: Is there any documentation about onSavedStateInstance for Flutter? Google couldn't find anything.

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537347/how-to-save-last-opened-screen-in-flutter-app

Comment: Seems like a good answer for my second question, thank you! Hopefully someone will help me with the first one :)

Comment: Can you share us a snippet what you have so far for the question #1?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fnxgQHtJ this is my app

Answer (score 1):

Android specifically requires you to save state - since interactions with components in your app may be irrelevant, or even undesirable, to preserve. Additionally, it would make a lot of assumptions in order to do this.

Therefore, any state changes you want to preserve are generally stored in something like `SharedPreferences` which is like a database. You can also use the state bundle that is passed using `Intent`s, but often these intents are not always preserved or passed into your app as expected.

Comment: But how to avoid restarting playback?

Comment: ^^Save playback time and skip to there on app resume

Comment: Wondering about saving AR Session state... seems like a lot of overhead if even possible