# How to stay on same state even after restarting app in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to stay on the same page(such as otpPage)until and unless a condition is verified.

Condition networkutil.verify == "Y".

This is my main.dart

```
final routes = {
      '/':(context)=> SignIn()  ,
      '/SignIn': (context)=> SignIn(),
      '/Home': (context)=> Home(),
      '/Register': (context) => Register(),
      '/OtpPage': (context) => OtpPage()
};

class A extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: './',
        routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your current initial route is `/`, so if you want it to be `OptPage`, just set your initialRoute like that

Comment: You can check this answer it provides neccesseray information for thing you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545052/12880676

Comment: That answer helped !!! @Lunedor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BLoC Pattern, where you will put a condition :

if the user is registered, then Welcome page else, SignIn Page.

Hope you can get some idea from this repo:
https://github.com/samrat19/login_bloc

Comment: Thats a good example!! But got a better answer. Thanks for the help