# How to open particular screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have three screen. screen 1 --> screen 2 --> screen 3

**I know how to open the (screen 3) in flutter.** May be I can use shared preferences but in my case i also want to pass the data from screen 1 to screen 2 then pass data to screen 3.

**Now i kill the app and i want to open the screen 3 directly without going through screen 1 and screen 2.**

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Check the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually the code is complex to write here. Can we use Flutter Provider to open particular screen without navigating the middle screens ?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the data through constructor ,
and then when you instantiate it you can pass the data for example,
you have your login second page which takes phone number from first loginpage

```
class LoginSecondpage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phone;

  const LoginSecondpage({Key key, this.phone})
```

then when you can use `navigator.push` or what ever you want and pass the data when you instantiate that
in my case i used `navigator.pushandremoveuntil` in my `firsloginpage`

```
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder(context)=>LoginSecendpage(phone:_phoneNumberContriller.text,)),
                        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                      );
```

then when you wanted to use it if class is stateless you only need to do this

```
Text('${phone}')
```

but if it is stateful you got to say

```
Text(${widget.phone})
```

Comment: kindly check my updated questions and please suggest me any particular way to do this.

Comment: about your updating i can say if you have data in somewhere special, you can use them in screen 3 put screen 3 in home: in main.dart like this home:Screen3(); home is where app shows primary page but if you don't have the data already then you can save them in `shared preferences` ,tell me the result

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting some keys/flags in shared preferences.

Step 1: Set a key/flag into shared preferences when you open screen 3.

Step 2: On your Splash screen, check if the key/flag is set. Then move/route accordingly.

Comment: can i use another technique other than shared preferences ?

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537347/how-to-save-last-opened-screen-in-flutter-app
Although this uses storage too. You need some kind of medium to let your application know about which route to follow after the application is killed.